# How to satisfy this dependency requirements?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

```
pathlib==1.0.1; python_version < "3.4"
```

I am installing a requirements.txt by:

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

This is a third party software. I am seeing one line was like above in the requirements.txt. Does it mean it must have Python version < 3.4? However, the python in my environment is Python 3.7.

It didn't report any error. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line does not mean the program requires python earlier 3.4. The part after the semicolon (`;`) is an environment marker - **if** you have a python version earlier than 3.4, `pathlib` 1.0.1 is required. If you have a newer version of python, `pathlib` is not required.